# Conditionally set form submit action

Tags: php, forms

```
<form action="<?php if(isset($redirect)&& $redirect == "f"){echo "#";} 
else{ ?>add_new_item2.php?user_id=<?php echo $_GET['user_id']; }?>" method="post"> 
//no need to expose this area here
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

//the processor

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$redirect = "f";
    if(whatever)
    {
     //the if condition comes here
    }
    else //all if conditions are satisfied
    {
       $redirect = "t";
    }
}
```

What i want to do is simple in the form action i want the action to be action="#" if the if conditions are not yet met and if they are met the action will be action="add_new_item2.php?user_id=123"

Comment: how you set `$redirect` value?

Comment: I think you want JavaScript. Look up the difference between server side and client side. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: oh my code has its own errors the $redirect = "f" is supposed to be outside the isset($_POST['submit']) then add Pragnesh Chauhan's answer :) i hope this question is helpful http://www.jaywebtechnologies.co.cc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$action = ''; 
if(isset($redirect) && $redirect == "f") {
  $action = "#";
} else {
  $action = "add_new_item2.php?user_id=".$_GET['user_id'];
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: oh yeah i haven't thought of this i really have a lot in mind and im in a rush, this one works well Pragnesh Chauhan i think this one is the best answer ill give my credits to you :) thanks although $redirect == "f" is supposed to be $redirect == "t" but thanks it's quite a big help :)

Answer (score 1):

You make condition before use means...

```
<?php
$action = ''; 
if(isset($redirect) && $redirect == "f") {
  $action = "#";
} else {
  $action = "add_new_item2.php?user_id=".$_GET['user_id'];
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

If redirect value is set already. Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to make action to current page.

Check the quotes `$redirect == "f"`. It should be single quotes or escape properly.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" 
      action="<?php 
             if(isset($redirect)&& $redirect == 'f'){echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];} 
             else{ echo 'add_new_item2.php?user_id='.$_GET['user_id']; }
            ?>"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting single quotes before and after your double quotes. Similiar to this:

```
<input type=label name=\"Description1\" value='". $T_Description. "' style=\"width:650px; margin-left:50px; padding: 5px;\" \>
```

(value = ' " **x** " ' )
Hope this helps...