# How to make a redirect in PHP using the query result to set the action field in form?

Tags: php, sql-server, forms, bootstrap-modal, post-redirect-get

I am new to PHP/Sql server. What I am trying to do here is to set the 'action' field of a 'Modal' to be determined based on the query result.If the query is valid , then it will redirect the page where the result will be shown , otherwise it will go back to the search page .

Here is the code snippet for Modal

```
<!--modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="my_modal" role="dialogue">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <strong> Provide your credentials to proceed </strong>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <form  name="mform" action="" method="post" id="mform" >
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <label  for="first">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group  ">
                                <label class="control-label"  for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group  ">
                                <label class="control-label"  for="con">Contact No</label>
                                <input type="text" name="con" id="con" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group  ">
                                <label class="control-label"  for="DOB">Date of Birth</label>
                                <input type='datetime' name="DOB" id="DOB" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group  ">
                                <label class="control-label" for="con">Policy No</label>
                                <input type="text" name="pon" id="pon"  class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" name="msubmit" id="msubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;" value="Submit">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>Submit
                                </button>
                            </div>



                        </form>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--modal-->
```

The action field in the #my_modal is kept blank , as i intend to according to the query result.

here is the php code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['msubmit']) == 'Submit') {
    include './verify_dob.php';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $contact = $_POST['con'];
    $policy_no = $_POST['pon'];
    $DOB_str = $_POST['DOB'];
    echo '<br>';
    $action = verify_dob($DOB_str, $policy_no);
    echo $action;
    if ($action) {
        echo "<script  type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Success');";
        echo "</script>";

        $URL ='showInfo.php?pon='.$policy_no; //redirect if the $action is true
        echo "<script>location.href='$URL'</script>";
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        echo "<script  type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "</script>";

        $URL ='index.php';  //otherwise
        echo "<script>location.href='$URL'</script>";
        exit(0);
    }
}
?>
```

The function *verify_dob()* is given here

```
<?php
$action = '';

function verify_dob($DOB_str, $policy_no) 
{
    require './connection.php';
    $cr_vw_chk = "IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.vw_search_verify') IS NULL
    exec ('
    CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_search_verify
    AS
    SELECT Policyno, Dateofbirth FROM dbo.tbl_Traditional_Policysummery3')

    ELSE
    exec('ALTER VIEW dbo.vw_search_verify
    AS
    SELECT Policyno, Dateofbirth FROM dbo.tbl_Traditional_Policysummery3')";
    $vw_chk_q = sqlsrv_query($con, $cr_vw_chk);

    $check_dob = "select Dateofbirth from vw_search_verify where Policyno='" . $policy_no . "'";
    $check_dob_q = sqlsrv_query($con, $check_dob);

    if (sqlsrv_fetch($check_dob_q) === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $dt = new DateTime($DOB_str);

    $date_db = sqlsrv_get_field($check_dob_q, 0);

    $interval = $dt->diff($date_db);

    if ($interval->format('%a') === '0') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

the purpose of the function is verify whether the inserted DOB is matching with the DOB in DB.With that in mind a view is created.

After clicking the submit button in Modal, the code is supposed to go "showInfo.php"  along with get value policy no.
otherwise it should  return back to the previous page.

I have also used **header** of php, but it is showing header value is already passed. 
while trying to get advantage of jQuery , onsubmit event , i tried to pass  the js variables to php function. As these two languages differ, that is no longer an option. 
I have used sql server 2014 as the back end.
How do I accomplish the task ????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097150/conditionally-set-form-submit-action

Using the first provided solution , I tried to return value for the action field, But alas, only error that i can see.

Comment: `include './verify_dob.php';` Dont you mean `../`